# How can I exchange 2 attributes from my App Store version to my current development version?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

How can I exchange 2 attributes from my App Store version to my current development version?
The problem is that I'm not changing the data model, so there is no a data model migration.
I tried adding a new data model version (without any change from the last one) , creating a mapping model and a custom entity migration policy that do this attribute exchange in createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance.
It doesn't work because the migration is never called. After some tests, I relised is called only if the second data model is different, but not equal, and this is what I want.
Do you have any idea or suggestion?
The only idea I have is creating a dummy attribute or something like that to create a different data model that will force launching the migration process.
Thanks a lot.
Ricardo.

Comment: Did you mark the new data model version as the active one?

Comment: Yes. I think core data knows that I didn't really change my data model, and then it skips the migration. Not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not changing the data model, the migration functionality is not what you want. It is like shooting at sparrows with cannons.

Just keep a user preference flag to check if the attribute has been updated. Alternatively, you could check with a fetch.

Then just do the update of the attributes "manually", maybe in `applicationFinishedLaunching`.

```
if (needsUpdate) {
   // fetch the concerned entities
   // iterate through fetchedObjects and change the concerned attributes
}
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

To be on the safe side you can do this on a separate thread using `NSManagedObjectContext`s `performBlock:`.

Comment: Thanks Mundi. That's exactly what I think regarding the migration.
The problem I see with your solution is that you can apply that update several times, as many as updates you release. In other words, there must be some kind of version control. Perhaps testing against CFBundleVersion, but as far as I know, it's not possible getting the bundle version that is about to be updated by the user.
Perhaps adding a dummy attribute is the most practical approach, because model mappings are applied in serial, one after another and for specific versions. What do you think?

Comment: As stated, it's overkill. Keep a version user preference, if necessary. If you insist on using the migration infrastructure, just *rename* one attribute, and the migration should trigger. Make sure you global replace the attribute name in your code.